# Play json absent-sensitive Reads

Tags: json, scala, playframework, algebraic-data-types, play-json

I'd like to have a reads like `Reads[Patch[T]]` for a case class like this

```
sealed trait Patch[+T]
case class Update[+T](value: T) extends Patch[T]
case object Delete extends Patch[Nothing]
case object Ignore extends Patch[Nothing]
```

where a missing json value reads to `Ignore`, a null json value reads to `Delete` and a valid present value reads to `Patch`.

Is it possible to implement a `Reads` like this?

Json4s has a `JNothing` type, does play json have some way to achieve the same functionality (I know there is no nothing type under JsValue)?

Edit: for context on how this might be used see the [json merge patch rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396).

Comment: Does it really make sense to have `value: Nothing` in such sealed family where only one kind can have value?

Comment: @cchantep in a sealed family like `Patch` or like `JsValue`? For json values it's just one way libraries like Json4s address functionality around serializing/deserializing models for questions like "how do I write a null value vs not writing the field at all", or in my case "how do I distinguish between a null field and an absent field".

Comment: I don't see benefit of having such `value` fiels in the base trait. Otherwise Play JSON is using `Option` with `None` as missing or null JSON.

Comment: @cchantep I'm not particularly interested in what implementations `Jsvalue` has. I'm just looking for any available method for implementing a `Reads` for the above `Patch` trait.

Comment: You can be not interested in, but the way Play JSON represent a missing value (`value: Nothing`) is mostly by using `Option.empty`. Note that the supported for sealed family encode the type of each sub-type a discriminator field in a `JsObject`.

Comment: @cchantep sorry, I'm not understanding what you're trying to say very well. I didn't get that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside discussions of whether `Patch[Nothing]` is a good idea, if we use this family of objects:

```
sealed trait Patch[+T]
case class Update[+T](value: T) extends Patch[T]
case object Delete extends Patch[Nothing]
case object Ignore extends Patch[Nothing]
```

We can get the desired behaviour by implementing a wrapper class:

```
case class PatchContainer[T](patch: Patch[T])
```

We have to do this as otherwise we lose the all-important distinction between a `null` value and a completely missing `patch`.

Now we can write a `Reads` for a `PatchContainer[T]` as long as we supply a suitable `Reads[T]` (e.g. for a `String` or `Int` etc):

```
class PatchContainerJson[T](implicit val rdst:Reads[T]) {

  implicit val patchContainerReads = new Reads[PatchContainer[T]] {

    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[PatchContainer[T]] = {
      json.validate[JsObject].map { obj =>
        (obj \ "patch").asOpt[T].fold[PatchContainer[T]] {
          if (obj.keys.contains("patch")) {
            PatchContainer(Delete)
          } else {
            PatchContainer(Ignore)
          }
        } { v =>
          PatchContainer(Update(v))
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The "trick" here is detecting whether there is a `patch` key in the object (using `keys.contains`), to get the desired `Delete` vs `Ignore` behaviour.

Examples of usage:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val json = Json.parse(""" { "patch": 42 } """ )
json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"patch":42}

scala> val pcti = new PatchContainerJson[Int]()

scala> import pcti._

scala> val result = json.validate[PatchContainer[Int]]
result: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.PatchContainer[Int]] = JsSuccess(PatchContainer(Update(42)),)

scala> result.get.patch
res0: models.Patch[Int] = Update(42)
```

and

```
...
scala> val ignoredJson = Json.parse(""" { } """) 

scala> ignoredJson.validate[PatchContainer[Int]]
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.PatchContainer[Int]] = JsSuccess(PatchContainer(Ignore),)
```

and

```
scala> val deleteJson = Json.parse(""" { "patch": null } """)

scala> deleteJson.validate[PatchContainer[Int]]
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.PatchContainer[Int]] = JsSuccess(PatchContainer(Delete),)
```

Comment: An interesting approach, looks similar to `nullableWithDefault` is implemented. Is it correct to say that using this would either require a change in the structure of the json or a custom reads for each object that contains a `Patch`?

Comment: Well, with the problem as you've defined it, a `Patch[T]` can't really exist without a containing object (otherwise the whole existence-check aspect doesn't make sense). So yes, the reads for each `Patch`-containing object would need to use something like the above. Or you could make `PatchContainer[T]` a trait and import the custom reads wherever it's needed. But it shouldn't need changes to any JSON structure